# python - passing variables between functions

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I am having trouble passing this dictionary between one function and another.

```
def player_main():
    player = {"health" : 100,
              "xp" : 100,
              "strength" : 0,
              "dexterity" : 0,
              "wisdom" : 0,
              "level_req" : None,
              "health_spawn" : None,
              "enemy_hit" : None}
    choice = difficulty_sequence()
    if choice == "easy":
        player = easy_difficulty(player)
    elif choice == "hard":
        player = hard_difficulty(player)
    player = character_creation(player)
    print(player)
    return player
```

In theory my second function should call 'player' from the first. The second isn't altering the values of it at all, but several of its variables depend on the first function.

```
def enemy_flail():
    print("Flail!")
    player = player_main()
    stat = player["strength"]
    print(stat)
    damage = stat//4 + 5
    print(damage)
    return damage
```

Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Edit - enemy_flail() won't print either stat or damage, which leads me to believe it isn't calling player_main() in the first place.

Comment: What exactly should happen?

Comment: No, because you haven't described what is actually wrong. What is happening that shouldn't be, or isn't happening that should?

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `enemy_flail` you are creating a new `player` dictionary, resetting all of the values.